# Get list of values for each unique key of json with jq

Tags: json, jq

guys. There's the task: to get all unique keys and lists of matching values for these keys and then wrap them in {}

The json looks like:

```
{
    "sepalLength": 5,
    "sepalWidth": 3.3,
    "petalLength": 1.4,
    "petalWidth": 0.2,
    "species": "setosa"
  },
  {
    "sepalLength": 7,
    "sepalWidth": 3.2,
    "petalLength": 4.7,
    "petalWidth": 1.4,
    "species": "versicolor"
  },
  {
    "sepalLength": 6.4,
    "sepalWidth": 3.2,
    "petalLength": 4.5,
    "petalWidth": 1.5,
    "species": "versicolor"
  },
...
```

And the result must look this way:

```
{
    "species": ["setosa", "setosa", ...],
    "petalWidth": [1.2, ...],
    ...
}
```

Comment: What have you tried, yet? https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'm new here and I didn't know about this rule. 
I have tried this:
jq '. as $glob | foreach [[.[] | keys[]] | unique[]][] as $item (0; .+1; "\(.) - \($glob[$item])")' iris.json
But the error occured. I haven't use jq before, so I make stupid mistakes)

Comment: No pb. Welcome to SO. Next time, edit your question to show the code, don't put it in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, your input data is an array

```
[
  {
    "sepalLength": 5,
    "sepalWidth": 3.3,
    "petalLength": 1.4,
    "petalWidth": 0.2,
    "species": "setosa"
  },
  {
    "sepalLength": 7,
    "sepalWidth": 3.2,
    "petalLength": 4.7,
    "petalWidth": 1.4,
    "species": "versicolor"
  },
  ...
]
```

The following

```
jq '[(map(keys[]) | unique[]) as $key | {($key): map(.[$key])} ] | add'
```

if fed with your sample data will produce something like

```
{
  "petalLength": [1.4,4.7,4.5],
  "petalWidth": [0.2,1.4,1.5],
  "sepalLength": [5,7,6.4],
  "sepalWidth": [3.3,3.2,3.2],
  "species": ["setosa","versicolor","versicolor"]
}
```